# Handling HTTP error with async await and try and catch clause in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, try-catch, http-error

I have the following code!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>();
 async function fetchMoviesHandler() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);
try {
      const response = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/film/");

      const data = await response.json();
const transformedMovies = data.results.map((movieData: any) => {
        return {
          id: movieData.episode_id,
          title: movieData.title,
          openingText: movieData.opening_crawl,
          releaseDate: movieData.release_date,
        };
      });
setMovies(transformedMovies);
} catch (err: any) {
setError(err.Message);
      console.log(err);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <section>
        <button onClick={fetchMoviesHandler}>Fetch Movies</button>
      </section>
      <section>
        
        {!isLoading && movies.length > 0 && <p>Movies fetched!</p>}
        {!isLoading && movies.length === 0 && !error && <p>Found no movies.</p>}
        {!isLoading && error && <p>{error}</p>}
        {isLoading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      </section>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here the URL is incorrect and the 404 error would be thrown and I wanted that error message to be displayed. When I console.log the error message is displayed on the console but the error message is not displayed on the webpage. Would appreciate it if someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the [Fetch docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status
> even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500.  Instead [...] the Promise
> will resolve normally (with the ok property of the response set to
> false if the response isn’t in the range 200–299)

So the `catch` clause in `fetchMoviesHandler` doesn't get immediately executed when you get the 404 response, it only executes when you try to parse the body from the response (`const data = await response.json()`), as there's no json to parse there. That's when the error is actually thrown and catched, but then there's no `Message` property on it, so nothing to show: the property on the built-in error object is `message`.

In order to handle this situation you should check for the `ok` property in the HTTP response and throw a specific error. Something like this:

```
async function fetchMoviesHandler() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/film/');
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong');
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      const transformedMovies = data.results.map((movieData: any) => {
        return {
          id: movieData.episode_id,
          title: movieData.title,
          openingText: movieData.opening_crawl,
          releaseDate: movieData.release_date,
        };
      });
      setMovies(transformedMovies);
    } catch (err: any) {
      setError(err.message);
      console.log(err);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Seems like the problem is with 'err.Message' whereas it should be 'err.message'. Its working without the if (!response.ok) cause I'm doing a try catch clause so then when there is an error it would actually move to the catch clause. But seems like the in built err.message should be the one called there. I infact got that one from your answer. Thanks once again and if possible edit the answer and I'd mark yours the correct one.

Comment: @kevinTHEprogrammer I added a mention of the `message` property, but I'll stick with the rest of my answer (feel free not to accept it though). Sure you would move to the catch clause in case of an error, but the point is that you're not catching the error you're supposed to catch. You're catching the parsing error, not the 404. This might be fine in your case, but not in general: e.g. the server might send back a 400 response with a parseable JSON, then you won't have any parsing error (maybe a different one when mapping the results). The point of the answer is: handle errors specifically.

Comment: thanks. that makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

The `setError` should be `setError(err.message)` m in message should be lowercase. It's a pity if you are using VSCode it doesn't show any errors.